# Get the row/col of a clicked drawing?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I assign to a cell in each row a png icon and a script with

```
sheet.insertImage(blob, 11, i).assignScript("ClickMe");
```

At the end of the process I have a few hundred rows with buttons at the end. What I'm struggling to do at the moment is work out which row gets clicked on. I've tried a few likely candidates like

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var sheetName = ss.getSheetName();
  var activeRange = ss.getActiveRange();
  var selection = ss.getSelection();
  var ar = activeRange.getA1Notation();
  var cc = ss.getCurrentCell().getA1Notation();
  var scr = selection.getCurrentCell().getA1Notation();

  var ac = ss.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
  Logger.log("scr=%s, ar=%s, cc=%s, ac=%s", scr, ar, cc, ac);
```

but having clicked on the 9th line, the Logger.log says

```
[19-06-20 22:39:01:123 HKT] scr=A1, ar=A1, cc=A1, ac=A1
```

So the question is this: if someone clicks on the button on the 21st line, can the script figure out what line the click occurred on?

Comment: Hi, for me no way to do that. There is no event sent when you click the image to the function that is launched. For me I would go to have only one button and ask person to put mouse in the line they want to treat and when you run function you get the active range and treat the line.

Answer (score 2):

The other answer is that you need to make 21 helper functions,

what I imagine you have now (> binding script)

```
Button1 > script
Button2 > script
Button3 > script
Button4 > script

function script(){

//Do something
}
```

Instead you need

```
Button1 > scriptOne
Button2 > scriptTwo
Button3 > scriptThree
Button4 > scriptFour
```

with carrier functions:

```
function scriptOne (){script(1);}
function scriptTwo (){script(2);}
function scriptThree (){script(3);}
function scriptFour(){script(4);}
```

and then you have that info in the script function

> ```
>     function script(input){
>     var row = input;
>
>     //Do something
>     }
> ```

This does get tedious, and isn't exactly easy to generate in bulk, but if you have a fixed sheet, that might work.

You can also consider making the button a checkbox, and then making your script be "onEdit" and checking for which row the change occurred in. But the way you are currently thinking won't work because there is no way to bind the scripts passing a variable from the button itself. The script will see all of your current buttons as the exact same thing.

Answer (score 1):

It’s not possible to achieve exactly what you want in your code. This is because when you use the functions “getActiveRange” and “getSelection” [1], it returns the cell or cells that are being selected (have the focus on it). When you click in the inserted image, you’re not clicking the cell but only the image, so the focus is still in the first cell.

To obtain the cell where the image is anchored you can use the following snippet:

```
var image = sheet.insertImage(blob, 11, i).assignScript("ClickMe");
image.getAnchorCell().getA1Notation());
```

The problem is that you can’t pass any parameters in the assignScript function (like the cell position in this case), only the name of the function to run [2].

A possible workaround is to adjust  the size of the cell to contain the complete image. Once this is done, request to your users that they must first click in the cell and then in the image:

```
var image = sheet.insertImage(blob, 11, i).setHeight(20).setWidth(20).assignScript("ClickMe");
```

[1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range

[2] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/over-grid-image