# Dynamically Pull Data Onto Another Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have a spreadsheet that has a table of data pulled from an api endpoint, and I want the ability to select *something* in that row and then pull details for that row from another endpoint and populate it on another tab.

Originally my idea was to do this with an `image/button` on each row generated when I pull the data, but it seems like this is currently not supported(as seen in this question: [Get the row/col of a clicked drawing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56688428/get-the-row-col-of-a-clicked-drawing)).

Is there a way to actually do this?  I would prefer not

- to have to either preload all the data onto another tab as I populate the first one (this is slow) or
- force the user to enter data into a second tab and click a button there

(these are my two options at the moment).

Comment: To question closers, Not every question needs code. This isn't a "give me teh codez" question. It focuses clearly on one problem only - a strategy to get data to sheet2 based on sheet1 row selection

Comment: @Cooper I think OP doesn't need code. But  just a "general overall strategy" for this situation. I think it's a valid question. I don't think every question needs code. I don't think there are any other solutions to this issue either. If OP has trouble implementing a strategy, He can ask another question with code. But "as is", I believe this question is valid and ok.

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of things you can do:

- [`onSelectionChange`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onselectionchangee):

  - Use this trigger to check when selection changes in  sheet1 => use that to input a custom  formula in sheet2 => urlfetch the data in sheet2 using custom formula. The custom formula workaround is needed as this trigger is "simple" and can't do external http requests(but a custom function can)
- [Installable `Edit` trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable):

  - Use a "installable" edit trigger with a checkbox on sheet1 => urlfetch the data and `setValues()` to sheet2

Comment: I think the second approach would be better and more maintainable.

Comment: @Marios  Yes. I think so too(because it depends on a custom formula workaround). But you seem  to have a burning hate against  any thing related to onSelectionChange recently :) Any reason why?

Comment: First of all it can't work as an installable trigger (as you also mentioned). I believe a user can do many unintended selections which could result in running the trigger a significant amount of times. Of course you can put as many if conditions you like to make it operate under very specific cases. But at the end, the code is going to be executed multiple times which can cause delays/errors/lags/service errors. Google needs to implement separate selection triggers: switch between sheets, select a cell, select a column or row etc.

Comment: @Marios I see. I agree with most of your concerns.